# C Struct - how to print all inputs of a nested struc

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to print out all of the nested structure but my code will only print the first entry, for employees managed it is only printing out John and not George for employees managed by Olivia.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

struct Employee {
    char name[30];
    int age;
    int salary;
    int yrsWorked;
    char jobTitle[40]; 
};


struct Manager {
    char name[30];
    int age;
    int salary;
    struct Employee managed[20];
    int index;
};

void print_managerK(struct Manager str_arrK[])
{
    int k;

    for(k= 0; k<2; k++)
    {
        printf("Manager Name: %s\n", str_arrK[k].name);
        printf("Age: %d\n", str_arrK[k].age);
        printf("Salary: %d\n", str_arrK[k].salary);
        printf("Employees Managed: %s\n", str_arrK[k].managed);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){

    struct Manager managerDetails[2] = {
    {"Olivia", 52, 150000, { "John", "George"}},
    {"Vincent", 42, 160000, "Lucy"},
    };
    print_managerK(managerDetails);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need an extra for-loop where you print employees

Comment: I strongly recommend that you start by fixing all warnings. There are several problems with your code. If you use gcc at least use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have two arrays, you need two loops, or more generally, you have to iterate over every list/array. Ask yourself, how should the compiler know, how much output you want, if you do not tell it to do so.

Another thing:

```
void print_managerK(struct Manager str_arrK[])
```

you have to specify how much elements are stored in the array, e.g.

```
void print_managerK(struct Manager str_arrK[], size_t num_manager)
```

because arrays are decayed to pointer if passed as argument to functions, therefore there is no notion about the size of the array.

And you got lucky with this construct:

```
printf("Employees Managed: %s\n", str_arrK[k].managed);
```

Since the begin of the struct is an char array, the above does work, but the correct way to do it would be:

```
printf("Employees Managed: %s\n", str_arrK[k].managed[0].name);
                                                      ^
                                           or any valid identifier
```